# Android: layout_weight not working with Button and LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to have the buttons all the same size, and be all on the right side of the screen, no matter how much text is in the text view.

Right now, the buttons are next to the vertical LinearLayout (that consists of 2 TextViews) and are only in the right spot when one of the TextViews is more than one line.

I have tried adding the Button to a LinearLayout and giving it a weight, giving the TextViews each a weight, giving only the text-filled LinearLayout a weight, etc. to no avail.

I am wondering now if it is an issue because this isn't the main XML, but instead a repeated item? But I didn't think that would affect it.

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzIp6.png)

And this is the XML of the row item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Use `android:layout_weight="0"` on your button.

Comment: can you post the screenshot with the problem

Comment: @Psypher In the question I included a link to a screenshot of what it looks like currently

Comment: I see my question was downvoted, I apologize if it was asked poorly. Thank you all for your responses and I will try some soon, however they are all different approaches to solve the issue, does anyone know what exactly is wrong with what I had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different layouts you could use to achieve the design you want. This is an approach you could use by changing the outer Layout element from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note you only need to add the attributes:

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
```

to the inner `LinearLayout` and add this attribute to the `Button` view:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

You can add `Margin` attributes to give the views some extra room.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the only response that works correctly. Could you by any chance point out exactly what was wrong about my initial approach? I am new to Android layout and do not want to make similar mistakes in the future

Comment: @Zuki :: You really were not too far off with your original layout, but `weightSum` and `layout_weight` have always been hard to deal with--and a lot of trial and error to get it right. In the early days of Android development `layout_weight` was the only way to get "relative"  positioning. Lucky google has added many new `Layout` schemes since which makes it much easier to get the design you want--much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your xml should be for what you need

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong this will make the two views (LLayout and Button) occupy 50% of the width as they both have same weight and their parent has weightSum 2. It is a good idea however. The only fix I'd make is to set button width to a fixed one or wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this with a ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This does not work, there is instead 3 buttons on the left side of the screen in spaces that occupy 1/3 of the screen each, and there is no text visible

Comment: Not sure how you would end up with 3 buttons... This should add one button tied to the right side of the screen and two TextViews on the left for each row.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 3 total on screen, they were each in a row with the row taking up 1/3 of the screen and the buttons were all on the left. I do not know why it doesn't work when it seems like it should

Comment: Alright, well it looks like you got something working with RelativeLayout, so best of luck. I just looked up one of my versions and I got the layout_height wrong, it should be wrap_content (updating answer), which is probably what was messing it up.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your answer and help. I would upvote you answer if I could however I do not have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation containing 2 views :

- Your text container (maybe a vertical LinearLayout with two TextViews). **Make LinearLayout width 0dp and weight:1**
- Your button (maybe with some side margins and a fixed width)

So practically the first LinearLayout will fill all the available horizontal space therefore pushing the button to the right edge.

A little sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some random text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So basically you'd get something like this [image]

Comment: Thank you, I do understand the idea. However I have copied this code and idea exactly and while I understand it, I am getting the exact same issue, with the buttons still not at the edge

Comment: So I seen you've already accepted @Barns solution. However I edited my answer so if someone wants to stick to LinearLayouts they could give it a try. I'm sorry for the previous code, it had some minor syntax errors (as I mentioned, I haven't tested it). I decided to use directly the first layout as a space-fill layout as the Space view could give problems if text was larger then one line.